# Decorator Pattern on List<T> for DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, decorator, generic-list

I would like to apply a Decorator on List class and be able to bind it to the WinForms DataGridView.

I would like to know what members of List I need to implement for this new class to be able to bind it to the DataGridView?

Some of the methods from List I would hide with my decorated class methods and others I would just call _decoratedList.Method().

Is this an option for implementing Decorator on List type?

Decorator (now changed to use IList):

```
public class MyCustomList : IList<MyObject>
{
  IList<MyObject> _decoratedList = new List<MyObject>; 

  // implementing all the required method with _decoratedList.BaseMathodName()
.
.
.
}
```

The idea is to have a class that I can just bind as a datasource to the DataGridView, use the List methods that I need and not write them all myself and add some new methods to this new class.

Comment: which platform are you using? wpf silverlight asp.net winforms?

Comment: WinForms I would like to bind this new class to the DataGridView component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at a minimum it just needs `IList`. Since you are inheriting `List<T>` you get that for free, but note that inheritance != decorator, and note that `List<T>` doesn't have virtual methods (though `Collection<T>` does) - so you can't customise... *anything* much by inheriting `List<T>`.

Fortunately, you *can* do a simple pseudo-decorator by implementing `IListSource` (but manually implementing `IList` would be preferred), as `IListSource` gets used **first**.  For type metadata, you need either a typed (non-object) indexer, or `ITypedList` (harder) - so:

```
public SomeType this[int index] { get {...} }
```

other **optional** interesting interfaces include `IBindingList`, `IBindingListView` and a range of others for side functions; `IRaiseItemChangedEvents` and `ICancelAddNew` for example.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I would prefer to have List<MyObject> as an ancestor class cause I would then just call _decoratedList.Method() for the newly introduced method. I would just like to know what do I need exposed from the Decorator for the DataGridView binding to work?

Comment: @elector the things mentioned above ;p

Comment: @elector - you know you have two lists there right? you *are* a list, and the list *has* a list...

Comment: @Mark I know about the lists, I guess that's what makes it a Decorator isn't it?
So you are saying I need to use Collection<T> instead of List<T>?

Comment: @Mark How abour if I use IList<T> for the ancestor?

Comment: @elector - even if you epose it as `IList<T>`, dgv only cares about `object`, and the object **must** implement the non-generic `IList`

Comment: @elector - re decorator; I would expect a decorator to encapsulate *only* - i.e. *wrap* a concrete list, not *be* a concrete list

Comment: @Marc Thank you Marc, I really do appreciate your answers but they are just to abstract for me. I don't understand what are you saying in the last comment. Sorry.

Comment: @elector - ah, right - you've changed the question. Now that you implement `IList<T>` rather than inherit `List<T>` *that* looks like a decorator. But you still need to implement non-generic `IList` for it to work

Comment: @Marc Yes I did change the question after I've looked at the definition of Decorator. But I still don't get the implementation of IList. Where to implement it? Thanks

Comment: @elector on whatever you give to DataGridView, i.e `grid.DataSource = obj`, then `obj` must either implement `IList`, or must implement `IListSource` to *generate* an `IList`

Comment: @Marc so my decorator must inherit from IList as well? public class MyCustomList : IList<MyObject>, IList ? And implement it's members?

Comment: yes (well, the correct terminology would be "implement", not "inherit" - but yes). If you have a ***range*** of decorators and don't want to do it for each, you could write a decorate that wraps `IList<T>` and exposes `IList`, and just implement `IListSource` on each, returning this. If you only have one decorator just implement `IList` directly.